# Commit message pattern is not applying when commiting

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, jira, issue-tracking

In IntelliJ, I installed the Atlassian connector in order to view my Jira issues within the IDE. I then integrate the issue server with IntelliJ tasks by configuring it in *Tasks -> Servers* in my project settings.

In this configuration, I can set a pattern for Commit messages so when I decide to commit changes, the commit message will follow this pattern. However this is not working, when invoking Commit Changes for a specific changelist the commit message is always the changelist name.

I'm using Subversion as VCS. I googled for a while and I found some results that talk about an "Amend commit" checkbox in the commit window when using Git. However I can't find this checkbox.

Is this feature—commit message pattern—related to the VCS used? and does IntelliJ provides a support for the case of Subversion?

Comment: Customizing commit messages based on doesn't seem to be currently supported. Please track https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66355 to be notified when support is added

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was to check the Add commit message checkbox in the Commit Message tab so that the generation of the commit message will take effect.